# Cross apply in Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use SQL Server 2008 CROSS APPLY with LINQ-2-SQL?

Example SQL:

```
select d.dateCol, tvf.descr, tvf.value
from dateTable d
cross apply tvFunction(d.dt, 'anotherParam') tvf
where d.category='someCat'
```

CROSS APPLY enables using values from a table (dateTable in the example) as parameters to a tablevalue function. This is very usefull if you need do do a complex calculation (encapsulated in a table value function) for a range of inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to use it would be to wrap the above code in a stored procedure and wrap it with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Of course that is a way to do it, or resort to a DbDataReader (which is what I did)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from d in dateTable
from tvf in tvFunction(d.dt, 'anotherProgram')
where d.category = 'someCat'
```

Comment: If chaining method calls, use `SelectMany`, which allows you to include lambdas for specifying both the function call and the shape of the result.