# LINQ to SQL cross apply

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, cross-apply

I would like to create a query with a cross apply into a user defined table value function in LINQ.  The SQL would be really rather simple as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable mt
CROSS APPLY MyTVF(mt.id)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492683/how-to-limit-a-linq-left-outer-join-to-one-row/492709#492709) post gives an example of a LINQ query that results in generated sql that contains both a cross apply and an outer apply but only for a sub query not for a tvf.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) article confirms that LINQ to SQL will generate cross apply and outer apply operators for "relationship navigations" but I am not sure what that means in this context.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209376/cross-apply-in-linq) post describes pretty much what I want to do and the answer says the only way to do this is to wrap the SQL query in a stored procedure and then call the sp via LINQ.  I hope that this is not true because I actually need a tvf that can be used in this way throughout an application in multiple LINQ queries so "wrap it in an sp" would not work for me.  Does anyone know of a way to get something like the simple SQL statement above via LINQ?

Comment: keep in mind, that relation between linq and SQL isn't surjective, so not every SQL command can be interpreted via linq.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this:

```
from mt in db.MyTable
from mf in db.MyTVF (mt.id)
select new { mt.Blah, mf.Blah }
```

Comment: Yeah that totally works, i can't beleive i didn't even try that.  Nice one thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var query = ActivityRepository.Where(p => p.iAction > -1 && userIds.Contains(p.iSellerId)).GroupBy(c => c.iSellerId).Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.dBeginTime).First()).Select(a => new ActivityInfo
        {
            ActivityId = a.iActivityId,
            StartTime = a.dBeginTime,
            SellerId = a.iSellerId,
            EndTime = a.dEndTime,
            ActivityName = a.sName,
        });
```

the keypoint is :**.Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.dBeginTime).First())**

Comment: Interesting to know.  I've pretty much moved over to EF these days, haven't used LinqToSQL for a couple of years.